# JavaScrpit crashes when incrementing by 2 in a for loop

Tags: javascript

before you call me out for using wrong terms or sth, I am a newbie programmer.

So, this would be the correct form of the code I'm experimenting with:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2) {
    nums.push(i);
}

console.log(nums) 

However, I don't get why I need to put the = sign after the +. I tried to research this but I couldn't find anything. When I removed the =, JS (Scrimba) crashed. Can anyone explain this to me please?
```

Answer (score 1):

The third expression in the for loop is to indicate how the `i` variable increases. This expression is run after every loop iteration.

The second `i<=10` is the **condition** that has to be true for the loop to continue.

Now in your loop starts with `i=0`, then `i=2` is run after 1st iteration. And after every iteration `i=2`. So `i<=10` is true, which is the condition. So this is an infinite loop, leading to the crash.

`i+=2` is shorthand for `i = i +2`, so `i` is increasing everytime and at some point will exceed 10.

This assumes you have defined nums at top like:
`var nums = []`. Otherwise you get a different error.

Answer (score 0):

i += 2 mean i = i + 2. In this context, for(A；B; C)，C part will run every time in every loop. If you only use "+",  the i value will never changed, and loop will be non-stop considering your judgement to stop the loop i < 10 equal to 0 < 10, which is true forever.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at for loop before go to your problem:

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

**Statement 1** is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.

**Statement 2** defines the condition for executing the code block.

**Statement 3** is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

**If you want to end the loop, statement 2 should return a false value.**

In your case:

statement 1 is `i=1` -> Assign 1 to i variable.

statement 2 is `i<=10` -> Execute the code inside brackets if and only if i is less than or equal to 10

statement 3 is `i+=2` -> in crease i by 2 after every run.

the point is if you change statement 3 to `i+2`, it is not an assignment statement anymore, but an operator. So the value of `i` won't be changed after statement 3 execution.
=> The value of `i` will always be 1
=> the statement 2 always returns true
=> infinite loop

So **your code crashes because of an infinite loop**

Answer (score -1):

`i += 2` means your are incrementing the value of `i` by `2`.

So, in your case, the loop will start from `0`, and it will push in your array. It will keep increasing your `i` value by `2` and pushing them in the array till it (`i`) becomes more than `10`